# Rails scope that filters by a minimum value in a corresponding has_many table

Tags: jquery, mysql, ruby-on-rails, join, scope

I need to create a scope on one model that filters against the minimum value of a column in another table which as a one to many relationship to the first table.

I have two classes, vastly simplified as below. An account has many scheduled payments, and the account scope needs to filter all accounts that have the next scheduled payment date after a certain date parameter.

The issue is that the below scope does not correctly filter against the single next scheduled payment record; it will find accounts that have any scheduled payment date after the given date (not the next most recent one).

This seems to require some fairly advanced custom SQL or a lateral join, but what is the best way to do this simply?

```
class Account
  has_many :scheduled_payments

  scope :scheduled_payment_date_after, ->(date) { joins(:scheduled_payments).where('scheduled_payments.date > ?', date).order(date: :asc).limit(1) }

end

class ScheduledPayment
  belongs_to :account
end
```

Comment: So to clarify: You want ONE account, the one with the scheduled payment date that is nearest but in the future of the given date? Or you want just the next future payment after a given date (i.e. limit 1) for all accounts that have a future payment?

Comment: A simplified expected  data result example is always helpful.